# VUEjs in AMBER embedded

Tags: vue.js, amber-framework

I want to use VUEjs with amber together. is this possible? Can I integrate the vue webpack to my amber application and use vue in my amber app?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/B6jJQdZ.png Sorry for the delay I'll publish it soon. I had some issues but they are already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the vue-webpack-boilerplate code in some subdir and set up a build step to build and deploy the vue app into public/ and just render() the html inside a view of the Amber app.

Comment: and how to make such build step?

Comment: Tbh i don’t know, I just started playing with amber but you can always script it out in some bash script or smth